# Field with one element and Chaitin's Constant

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, computer-science, riemann-hypothesis

Some quotes from Wikipedia:

> In mathematics, the field with one element is a suggestive name for an
> object that should behave similarly to a finite field with a single
> element, if such a field could exist. This object is denoted $F_1$,
> or, in a French–English pun, Fun. The name "field with one element"
> and the notation $F_1$ are only suggestive, as there is no field with
> one element in classical abstract algebra.
>
> The possibility of studying the mathematics of $F_1$ was originally
> suggested in 1956 by Jacques Tits, published in Tits 1957, on the
> basis of an analogy between symmetries in projective geometry and the
> combinatorics of simplicial complexes. $F_1$ has been connected to
> noncommutative geometry and to a possible proof of the Riemann
> hypothesis. Many theories of $F_1$ have been proposed, but it is not
> clear which, if any, of them give $F_1$ all the desired properties.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element

The axioms of a field are as follows:

> Formally, a field is a set $F$ together with two operations called
> addition and multiplication. An operation is a mapping that associates
> an element of the set to every pair of its elements. The result of the
> addition of $a$ and $b$ is called the sum of $a$ and $b$ and denoted
> $a + b$. Similarly, the result of the multiplication of $a$ and $b$ is
> called the product of $a$ and $b$, and denoted $ab$ or $a⋅b$. These
> operations are required to satisfy the following properties, referred
> to as field axioms. In these axioms, $a$, $b$ and $c$ are arbitrary
> elements of the field $F$.
>
> Associativity of addition and multiplication: $a + (b + c) = (a + b) +
> > c$ and $a · (b · c) = (a · b) · c$.
>
> Commutativity of addition and multiplication: $a + b = b + a$ and $a ·
> > b = b · a$.
>
> Additive and multiplicative identity: there exist two different
> elements $0$ and $1$ in $F$ such that $a + 0 = a$ and $a · 1 = a$.
>
> Additive inverses: for every $a$ in $F$, there exists an element in
> $F$, denoted $−a$, called the additive inverse of $a$, such that $a +
> > (−a) = 0$.
>
> Multiplicative inverses: for every $a ≠ 0$ in $F$, there exists an
> element in $F$, denoted by $a^{−1}$, $1/a$, or $\frac{1}{a}$, called
> the multiplicative inverse of $a$, such that $a · a^{−1} = 1$.
>
> Distributivity of multiplication over addition: $a · (b + c) = (a · b)
> > + (a · c)$.
>
> This may be summarized by saying: a field has two operations, called
> addition and multiplication; it is an abelian group under the
> addition, with 0 as additive identity; the nonzero elements are an
> abelian group under the multiplication, with 1 as multiplicative
> identity; the multiplication is distributive over the addition.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)

Chaitin's constant is defined as follows:

> Let $P_F$ be the domain of a prefix-free universal computable function
> $F$.
>
> The constant $\Omega_F$ is then defined as   $\Omega _{F}=\sum _{p\in
> > P_{F}}2^{-|p|}$,
>
> where
>
> $\left|p\right|$ denotes the length of a string $p$. This is an
> infinite sum which has one summand for every $p$ in the domain of $F$.
> The requirement that the domain be prefix-free, together with Kraft's
> inequality, ensures that this sum converges to a real number between
> $0$ and $1$. If $F$ is clear from context then $\Omega_F$ may be
> denoted simply $\Omega$, although different prefix-free universal
> computable functions lead to different values of $\Omega$.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin%27s_constant

As I understand it the digits of a Chaitin constant are undecidable, hence it is undecidable whether the set $\{\Omega_F\}$ together with the definitions $\Omega_F + \Omega_F = \Omega_F$ and $\Omega_F \centerdot \Omega_F = \Omega_F$ for addition and multiplication respectively, forms a field.

Thus we can assume that it does, taking this assumption as an axiom.

Does the assumed field $\{\Omega_F\}$ meet the requirements for a field with one element, does it have the necessary properties for why such an object was originally suggested?

Comment: The set {$r$} with non-zero real $r$ cannot form a field, no matter what $r$ actually is ,because of $\ r+r=2r\ne r$ . Chaitin's constant cannot be $0$, hence the set you suggest cannot form a field.

Comment: The last sentence of your first quoted paragraph says : "The name "field with one element" and the notation $F_1$ are only suggestive, as there is no field with one element in classical abstract algebra." This means that the "field with one element" is NOT defined as a one-element set endowed with some operations, as you suggest. And in any case, the only singleton where "usual definitions of real addition and multiplications" can define operations is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Sorry I might of made a mistake by saying taking the usual definitions of real addition and multiplication, but what if you took $\Omega$ + $\Omega$ = $\Omega$ and $\Omega \centerdot \Omega = \Omega$ as the definitions?

Comment: I have edited to change the definitions of addition and multiplication for $\{\Omega_F\}$ now. in light of the comments.

Comment: One consequence would be that the single element in the field would be both the zero - and the one - element. I do not think that this is allowed in a field.

Comment: You are mixing two relatively unrelated things. The field with one element does not exist - it is an analogy only. Every field has at least two elements. There is no real $x$ so that $\{x\}$ is a field.

Comment: If the digits of $\Omega_F$ are undecidable then one can assume the intuitively false statement that $\Omega_F \neq \Omega_F$ without fear of contradiction just as we can assume that the intuitively true Godel statement is false.

Comment: @YeatsL: when they say "the digits are undecidable" they only mean there is no computer program to print them out. The digits for each Chaitin number are completely well defined and specifically specified, and there is one Chaitin number for each universal prefix free code.  In the end the Chaitin numbers are just a particular family of uncomputable real numbers. There are many other uncomputable real numbers as well, and nothing about them is contradictory. They behave just like all other real numbers.  Some people give too much hype to Chaitin numbers, which are not really very special.

Comment: Godel's statement is completely well defined but undecidable. Thus one can assume it either to be true or false, in the same way Chaitn numbers are completely well defined but have undecidable digits, thus one can assume them to be equal to themselves or not.

Comment: @YeatsL Digits are, in particular, numbers; numbers follow specific laws, namely that a number is always equal to itself. It doesn't matter at all whether we know the number or not, whether we can compute it or not; if it is a number, it is equal to itself.

Comment: Set theoretically (in ZFC for example) to show that a number is equal to itself one has to prove that both contain the same elements i.e. $a \in r \leftrightarrow a \in r$, if it is undecidable if $a = n$ then proving existentiality (i.e. equality) is undecidable hence one can assume that $r \neq r$

Comment: @YeatsL: that is not the way that mathematics works. Regardless of whether $a \in r$ or $a \not \in r$, we still have $a \in r \leftrightarrow a \in r$.  At this point, I think it might be better for you to go back and learn more from the beginning; it seems like you don't have a handle yet on what 'undecidable' actually means. There's no benefit in continuing to press your argument on this site, when several have pointed out it isn't correct; instead, I'd recommend learning more mathematical logic. Internet sources can be particularly confusing - textbooks are better.

Comment: Sorry that should read "if it is undecidable that $\exists a, a \neq n$" I think...

Comment: "we still have $a \in r \leftrightarrow a \notin r$." Exactly and whether such a set exists is undecidable hence we can assume it does exist without contradiction.

Comment: I have proved Godel's theorem from first principles for which I got a first at university, but perhaps I was marked wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because a number's digits are undecidable doesn't mean every property of it is undecidable. More generally, just because an object $x$ has a property $\phi$ that's undecidable in a given axiom system (i.e., $\phi(x)$ is true in some models and false in others) doesn't mean there isn't a property $\psi$ that is decidable (i.e., $\psi(x)$ is the same in all models).

In particular, for all real numbers $x$ (including all Chaitin numbers), the property
$$
\psi(x) = \begin{cases}
  \mathrm{True} & if\ \ x=x \\
  \mathrm{False} & if\ \ x \neq x
\end{cases}
$$

is decidable. Namely, it's always true. The proof of this depends on what formal system you're working in; often it's just taken as an axiom of the underlying predicate calculus.

As such, the set $\{\Omega_F\}$ that you propose, where $\Omega_F$ is both the additive identity $0$ and the multiplicative identity $1$, does not satisfy the following field axiom for any Chaitin number $\Omega_F$:

$$
\mathrm{F4.}\quad 0 \neq 1.
$$

Therefore, it is never a field.

Comment: I'm still not convinced, I know this will annoy a lot of people, perhaps I am just very stupid and stubborn. The Godel statement "this statement has no proof" can be assumed to be false without fear of contradiction even though it is true at a meta-level, because consistency cannot be proved. Similarly F4 can be assumed to be true for the field I describe even though it is false, because again consistency cannot be proved. This is the meaning of undecidable. One can assume either way and with faith in mathematics proceed unhindered even though only one way is true at a meta-level.

Comment: I know it is hard to grasp for some, but the consistency of mathematics rests on faith alone and one can assume some false statements so long as they are isolated by self-reference.

Comment: That's not quite right. The Godel statement is independent of the corresponding formal system (that's literally the point of it), so you can safely assume it without fear of contradiction. The statement $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}[x=x]$ isn't independent or undecidable. It's perfectly decidable, namely it's false, so if we add it as an axiom, the resulting system is definitely inconsistent. Consider this: by your argument, we could just as easily declare $\{7\}$ to be a field (under the usual $+$ and $\cdot$). Or declare $2+2=5$, for that matter. Some things are undecidable; not *everything* is.

Comment: As for the philosophy of whether self-consistency is just taken on faith or whatever, that isn't really relevant. Whether or not ZFC or the theory fields or whatever is consistent, any of them plus the axiom "$\left\{\Omega\right\}$ is field" is *definitely* inconsistent, no faith required.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two relatively unrelated things. The field with one element does not exist - it is an analogy only. Every field has at least two elements. There is no real $x$ so that $\{x\}$ is a field.

The reason the field with one element was suggested is that some formulas that have a parameter for the size of a finite field still give interesting results if we plug in "1", although no field has only one element. Some people find it useful in these cases to pretend there is a field with one element, just to understand or state results in a convenient way. So the "field with one element" is just a mental or notational device, not an actual field.

When they say "the digits of a Chaitin number are undecidable" they only mean there is no computer program to print them out. The digits for each Chaitin number are completely well defined and specifically specified, and there is one Chaitin number for each universal prefix free code.  In the end, the Chaitin numbers are just a particular family of uncomputable real numbers. There are many other uncomputable real numbers as well - most real numbers are uncomputable - and nothing about them is contradictory.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: I give up, I think I am right, but there is no point in a protracted argument. Thank you to every one who commented.